# Backup dead MySQL server

Tags: mysql, xampp, backup

My computer went almost totally down and I now need to get the data out of it, before I reinstall it. One of the data I need to backup are those on the [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) server. However, I can't run it, so I just need to know, which files should I copy on external drive.

I have instaled MySQL with the [xampp](/questions/tagged/xampp) bundle. In the [xampp](/questions/tagged/xampp) main folder I can find mysql folder and within it, these folders:

```
..
backup
bin
data
include
scripts
share
sql-bench
```

Which of them contains the actual database data? I'm quite short on space so I need to only backup the most necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it should go without saying that backups are something you make *before* your computer dies, mistakes happen.

What you should do is image your drive, copy it to something else, in preparation for your reinstall. I'd recommend copying **everything** as authentically as you can, even if that takes a while. That feeling you get when you realize you forgot to salvage something important that is now gone forever is not good.

MySQL generally stores data in the `data` directory. It may take some work to get your MySQL back into the same configuration as before, so be sure to grab the appropriate `my.cnf` file.

It can be really difficult to extract data from a bunch of MySQL data files without the MySQL process actually running. This is why tools like `mysqldump` exist. If you can get it running, even limping along, that'll be good enough to snapshot it.

Comment: I said I'm short on space. That's why I just can't save whole drive as it is.

Comment: Oh, there is no `*.cnf` file in the mysql folder. However, there are several `.ini` files in the folder. Does any of these hold the settings you're talking about?

Comment: It might be worth grabbing an external USB drive of some sort, even a cheap thumb-drive or salvaged desktop drive in an external housing, as once you format the drive you might have regrets. The `ini` file may contain the information on how your MySQL is configured.

Comment: I'm in real hurry. Otherwise, I'd have enough time to upload the data somewhere. There are multiple `ini`s. I'll just have to risk it.

Comment: Hope it works out for you! In the future, schedule a recurring task to either `mysqldump` all databases, or use [`innobackupex`](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtrabackup/2.1/innobackupex/innobackupex_script.html) which is much faster for larger InnoDB dumps.