# Dump data from "data" folder mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database, restore, dump

I've saved "data" (/usr/local/mysql/data) folder on my mac after mysql server died.
How can i restore all tables?
Information stored there is very important for me.
I'll give bounty for answers.
+ i don't have my.cnf file.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Backup dead MySQL server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20130706/backup-dead-mysql-server)

Comment: Take it to someone who knows what they're doing - the way your question is asked implies that you do't have the knowledge to evaluate the outcome of a proposed solution nor to quanitfy the risks.

Comment: can you suggest me sb who knows what they're doing?

Comment: What db engine? MyISAM or InnoDb? What have you tried? There are quite a few similar questions...

Comment: i think innobd, cause tables have ibd and frm extensions

Comment: do you have any backup of database structure corresponding data you saved or may be you remember/have in svn this structure?

Comment: i have an sql with old data

Comment: Do you have an opportunity to install MySQL 5.6?

Answer (score 0):

Please go thru the next steps:

- restore last dump that you have;
- run sql statements to update your data structure if needed;
- follow the link: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/tablespace-copying.html (general idea: discard table space, copy ibd file, import table for table you have. run many times for partitioned tables) for innodb tables;
- copy all myd, myi for myisam tables.

hope it helps